# Godot how to delete a RigidBody node and its child nodes?

Tags: godot

Godot engine through gd script

I preload the tscn files and `main.add_child(item)`. How to delete this `RigidBody` node and its child nodes (`RigidBody` node with child nodes: a sprite node and a collider shape node)?

Comment: The question isn't specific to `RigidBody`, you might as well ask: How to delete a node and its child nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't enough info, or just incomprehensible for me, but to delete node with it children, you just need to delete the they parent node.

```
get_node("your_rigid_body").free()
```

or

```
get_node("your_rigid_body").queue_free()
```

if you want to delete it in next frame. ( I'm not sure about the second one )